# NSData Bytes to Float - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, floating-point, byte, nsdata

Is there any way I can convert the value of a [NSData bytes] to a float so that I can add it to a progress bar?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell: `[data length]`

Here is the snippet of how the download bar I use works.

```
// Can get called numerous times during download process
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
 // Accumulate incoming data into mutable data object
 [fileData appendData:data];
 byteCount += [data length];
 float progress = byteCount/(mapToDownload.fileSize);
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgress:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress] waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Let me know if you need more information.

**[Added Oct 26 to address your other question:]**

I have not worked with NSStream. My example is from an asynchronous NSURLConnection example. Therefore, let's ignore my previous code example.

You mentioned that you have `[NSData bytes]`. `[NSData length]` should return you how much data you have. Assuming you know the size to be downloaded then:

```
float progressPercentage = [yourNSData length]/knownFileSize;
```

should give you the percentage needed to update the progress bar. You could then set your progress bar:

```
[yourProgressBar setProgress:progressPercentage];
```

Comment: What are the variables fileData and byteCount? I use a NSStreamOutput when I receive the data so I don't use appendData. Would it be still safe to consider using it when I have NSStreamOutput at the same time?

Comment: No prob. Glad it was helpful.